# Where to use setTrustedProxies() or how to set new trusted proxies

Tags: proxies

I need to set a trusted proxy in my installation so that secure cookie flags are set correctly.

Currently as a temporary measure i am setting the following in index.php

```
$proxies = ['122.128.0.1'];
Request::setTrustedProxies($proxies);
```

However i would like to be able to set a new trusted proxy from a settings file or module that will persist through a core update without needed to patch.

Where is the best place to specify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal doesn't want you to place custom code in index.php to prepare a request before it is handled by the Drupal kernel. So it was made possible for modules to implement a middleware through [StackedHttpKernel](https://github.com/stackphp/builder/blob/master/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php).

In this case such a middleware already exists, which reads the reverse proxy addresses from settings.php and adds them as trusted proxies to the request:

[Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware::setSettingsOnRequest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StackMiddleware%21ReverseProxyMiddleware.php/function/ReverseProxyMiddleware%3A%3AsetSettingsOnRequest/8.6.x):

```
  $proxies = $settings->get('reverse_proxy_addresses', []);
  if (count($proxies) > 0) {
    $request::setTrustedProxies($proxies, Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL | Request::HEADER_FORWARDED);
```

So you can simply enable this settings in settings.php:

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = ['a.b.c.d', ...];
```

Answer (score 1):

All the other proxy settings are in [`settings.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/8.2.x) so I think that would be the most appropriate place.

This would persist after core updates and as a new developer on boarding onto a project that is the first place I would check for this sort of configuration.

Comment: Do you know exactly what the syntax is for setting them in settinsg.php?

Comment: You have the syntax right. See Drupal documentation on [`Request::setTrustedProxies`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AsetTrustedProxies/8.2.x) and there is an example of it in use on the [HttpCache.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21HttpCache%21HttpCache.php/8.2.x) page.

Comment: Ah ok, i thought there might have been a $settings['trustedproxies'] = [...] kind of syntax specifically for settings.php as i've never seen any direct code in a settings file before.

Comment: No, I don't think anything like that exists. There are a few modules that require adding small code blocks to settings.php so think it is fine.